# "Create Unique Index" on big table taking too long time

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, mysql-5.7, unique-constraint

I am trying to restore GHTorrent's database dumps (CSV files containing GitHub metadata). The `commits` table has more than 891 Million rows and the `project_commits` has more than 5.4 Billion rows. Since these tables are quite big I had to load them using `LOAD DATA INFILE` with foreign key check off. I am using `MyISAM` engine. After finishing importing records into the tables, I am trying to create indexes for these tables.

I am running the following mysql command for the `commits` table and it didn't finish in more than 12 hours.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `sha` ON `ghtorrent_restore`.`commits` (`sha` ASC)  COMMENT '';
```

The commits table looks like below:

[image]

I have read other stackexchange questions regarding slow indexing and set the following in `my.cnf` file in `/etc/mysql` directory.

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=1G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8G
key_buffer_size=6G
sort_buffer_size=10M
```

Since the previous command was not finishing in time, I had to stop it with ctrl+z from the console. I checked the table on MySQL workbench, it is not showing as corrupted, but it shows some 36GB as index length.

[image]

Importing this table took about 25 minutes, so I am expecting indexing it should not take more than an hour, but I am running the 'create unique index' command now for about 2 hours without any sign of progress.

When I run the command, mysqld takes a lot of cpu and it keeps taking memory. After reaching some 6GB it becomes less active and seems almost doing nothing.

[image]

Here is how the command (selected one in the following picture) looks from the mysql workbench.

[image]

I am running Mysql 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on a Linux Mint 17.03 machine with 16GB RAM.

Since I am not an advanced user, any help will be of great help.

**Update [as Wilson H. suggested]:**

**my.cnf file** [06/05/2018 01:06]

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""

[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=1G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8G
key_buffer_size=6G
sort_buffer_size=10M
```

Here are snapshots of **buffer** and **cache** related **variables**.

[image: buffer and cache related system variables]

I have not modified anything else in my mysql installation. Mysqld takes different amount of memory depending on different tables out of total 16GB ram available in the system. I do not run any cpu/memory intensive application beside mysql.

Interesting Observation: Some tests with other tables showing increasing time with respect to increasing number of rows. The trend looks polynomial.

[image: Polynomial increase of time]

The following stats were captured while the last mysql command from the above picture was being executed (i.e., indexing for table 'projects').

**top:**
[image: top]

**iostat -x:**
[image: iostat -x]

**ulimit -a:**

[image: ulimit -a]

**df -h:**

[image: df -h]

**Update 2:**
Since creating index on 'commits' table was not finishing, I was trying out other tables and finally I attempted indexing on the 'project_commits' table before sleeping last night. To my surprise, I found it took only 18 minutes to finish the indexing.

[image]

I didn't make any additional modification and I do not understand why 'commits' table is never finishing. I am running the indexing again on the 'commits' table and see how far it goes.

**Update 3:**

'SHOW CREATE TABLE commits;'

```
CREATE TABLE `commits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sha` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `committer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `commits_ibfk_1` (`author_id`),
  KEY `commits_ibfk_2` (`committer_id`),
  KEY `commits_ibfk_3` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=922093754 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**SHOW PROCESSLIST:**
[image: SHOW PROCESSLIST]

**Bottomline:**

Indexing for all tables are completed except for the 'commit' table (i.e., the following command is not finish executing).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `sha` ON `ghtorrent_restore`.`commits` (`sha` ASC)  COMMENT '';
```

When I am running a query (see the below picture) which counts about 19000 rows from 891 million rows, it takes about 76 seconds. Is this time too high given I have a computer with Core i707700HQ CPU @ 2.8Ghz x 4, 16GB DDR4 Ram and the database is installed on HDD with 7200RPM? **Does the 76 seconds indicate that indexing is not working properly in 'commits' table?** Please note that this query was executed right after booting the computer to avoid impacts from buffers.

[image]

Comment: Please post your complete my.cnf file for analysis in your original question labeled  my.cnf as of mm/dd/ccyy hh mm   We also need to know how much RAM is available to your server.  
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
   includes hda & sda (SSD) filesystem type clues. 
free -h  for a linux/unix Total Used Free  Mem: and Swap:,

Comment: You still haven't explicitly stated what your issue is. Or put differently: What is your actual question? Please consider asking an actual question. (e.g. How can I speed this up? Is this normal behaviour? ...). Thanks.

Comment: WilsonHauck and hot2use: Could you please look at the bottom-line section (at the end of the question) and give your thoughts about the query execution time?

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus Considering there is NO index for project_id, 76 seconds for counting ~ 19,000 found is quite reasonable.  Please consider posting on pastebin.com or here complete TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and complete report from Mysqltuner.pl for analysis.  Would like to Skype with you, view my profile, Network profile for Skype ID and other contact info.

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus Please review these specifics for your MyISAM table limit consideration  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html  you may be encountering limits without warnings or messages.  Just a thought.

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus Have you been able to CREATE INDEX on commits for SHA as we discussed yesterday.  When you look at SHOW INDEX FROM commits in the cardinality column, I suspect you will recognize the SHA values are not unique.  If the count is same as row count, they are unique.  Here is a link to CREATE INDEX syntax for v 5.7  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: @WilsonHauck I ran the create index command without ‘unique’ and it didn’t finish in about 4 hours.

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus Consider going to my website and look at Utility Scripts+, download script named globalstatusage10sec.sql to find out WHAT the system was doing after 3 hours.  This should give you a clue on GLOBAL STATUS usage any time you run the query.  It is LOW impact, sleeps most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems.

Auto_inc of 922M is half way to the 2 billion limit on `INT SIGNED`.  Suggest you change to `INT UNSIGNED` (4 billion limit) during the next `ALTER`.

MyISAM saves disk space, but is otherwise 'worse' than InnoDB.  Note:  changing to InnoDB will require changing several settings.

`FOREIGN KEYS` are ignored by MyISAM.

If `sha` is a SHA-1 hash, it is terrible for indexing.

If `sha` is a SHA-1 hash, it could be compressed to `BINARY(20)` via `UNHEX()`.  This would shrink the table by over 20GB, 30% of the current size!

If `sha` is a SHA-1 hash, don't use utf8; use ascii or latin1.

If `sha` is a SHA-1 hash, and that is the column you are creating the `UNIQUE` index on, check `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.  If it says "Repairing by key_buffer", then you should kill it; it will take *months* to finish.  If it says "Repairing by sort", then there is hope that it will finish.

Consider using smaller ids than the 4-byte INT for author, committer, and project -- unless you really have many billion distinct values.  Wait!  What?  Each of those is going to be `UNIQUE`?  I doubt it.

What `SELECTs` do you have?  Might some of them need 'composite' indexes?

Put multiple `ALTERs` (including creating indexes) into a single statement.  Each `ALTER` is a complete copy of the table (in MyISAM).

`myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8G` is half of RAM.  This is bad.  Suggest 3G.

**Polynomial**

> The trend looks polynomial.

I hope you are not adding a `UNIQUE INDEX` on a column on a table that *already* has the same column as `PRIMARY KEY`.  That would be totally redundant.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of them.

Why "polynomial"?  If it is (and I question such), then it would be because of the nature of "Repair by key_buffer":

For each row, look up the column in all unique (including primary) indexes to make sure it is not a "duplicate".  This lookup requires fetching the block of the index's BTree and putting it into the "key_buffer" for testing.  Depending on the 'order' of the key versus the 'order' of the data:

- For auto_increment or timestamp, where the row were inserted chronological (and the table had not become fragmented), the next block needed is very likely to be the one that was just touched.  This is the most efficient because it needs the least I/O.
- For SHA1/MD5/UUID/etc, this lookup will be jumping all around the index.  So the next block needed is less and less likely to be in the in-RAM key_buffer.  At the extreme, this leads to almost 1 disk read per lookup!
- For other indexes, the timing is somewhere in between.

Comment: Impressed with your suggestions! Thanks a lot.

I will check 'PROCESSLIST'. Figure 2 in the question shows 36.7 GiB for index length for the 'commits' table. I recognized even for some other table, there are values before executing 'CREATE INDEX' command. Do you know the reason for this? How can I be sure that indexing is done on the 'commits' table?

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus - MyISAM's `.MYI` file holds some dynamic, non-data, non-schema, information about the table, so it is at least 1024 bytes (1 "block").  In addition, that file holds any indexes (`PRIMARY` or secondary).  (Innodb works differently.)  The 36.7G indicates that there are some index(es); but it does not say how many indexes.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE commits` is reliable at listing all the indexes (but not the space taken).

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus - and I added some words about "polyonomial", though I think it is close to proportional to the table size.  Yes, there are variations, but I can't explain them without seeing the schema.

Comment: I have added 'show create table commits' and 'show PROCESSLISTS' results. For the latter, I see neither  "Repairing by key_buffer" nor  "Repairing by sort".

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` needs to be done via root while the `CREATE INDEX` is being done.

Comment: Both conditions were met. I further checked SHOW PROCESSLIST from the console and it shows the same result :(

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
E) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 2):

891 Million rows is quite a bit. This is a problem with MyISAM and unique indexes.

- [Bug #22487   mysql performs extremely slow when creating unique indexes on huge table](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22487)
- [WL#1333: Speed up ALTER TABLE (part 3: Rebuild unique indexes by sorting in ALTER TABLE)](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1333)

Perhaps you could migrate to [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), which doesn't have this problem? [ghtorrent seems to support PostgreSQL](http://ghtorrent.org/ght-ubuntu.html)